# Check if Native UI component does exist

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use a native UI component like the one declared [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html) and 
[here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html).

The problem is that I don't know if the corresponding native component is implemented or not.
If I am requiring a component that doesn't exist, like this:

```
requireNativeComponent('InexistentComponent', null);
```

I get this error:

```
Invariant Violation: Native component for "InexistentComponent" does not exist
```

Wrapping the code with a `try/catch` doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
try {
    const native = requireNativeComponent('InexistentComponent', null);
    return native;
} catch (_) {
    return null;
}
```

So is there a way of finding out if a component does indeed exist before requiring it with `requireNativeComponent`?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NativeModules.UIManager` to check if your component exists on that object's list of keys.

For example:

```
import { requireNativeComponent, NativeModules } from "react-native";

let CustomComponent = null;

if ("CustomComponent" in NativeModules.UIManager) {
   CustomComponent = requireNativeComponent("CustomComponent")
}
```